# How to prevent some elements from being exploded when uploaded to BIM 360 or Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

I have a Revit MEP element model with the element id and GUID as shown in the image:
[Revit model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq85h.png).
The model then uploaded to BIM 360 and shown in Forge Viewer.

As can be seen in the image, the model got exploded to 3 elements: [BIM360 element 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9QdH.png) [BIM360 element 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ll8O.png) [BIM360 element 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuhqM.png), one with the same GUID and element as in the Revit model and the other two are exploded elements with different GUID.

How can I prevent the uploaded model from being exploded?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The Forge Model Derivative service is more granular because in some cases customers might need to be able to select individual components of such MEP element. With that said, the translation output should still provide enough information for you to be able to find the objects and GUIDs that you need. Individual elements always use some form of an "external ID", and in case of Revit designs this should be the GUID:

[image]

Comment: If this doesn't work for your use case, please send us a sample Revit file with your MEP data to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` and we would investigate it with our dev. team.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually what I'm aiming is to have the same number of elements that are selected in Revit with what's in BIM 360 and Forge viewer. So I guess, I have to filter out the external ID using the Revit GUID then.

Comment: Btw. there's also a method on the viewer called [setSelectionMode](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setselectionmode-mode) that allows you to change the selection behavior, i.e., where in the model tree should the selection drill down stop. Give it a try, and if it doesn't fit your needs, you can always go back to filtering the external IDs.